# Bash script that print out usb serial number

Tags: bash

i am new to bash script. so,i need help. Below command print out USB serial number. But i don't how to store it in a string. Because i want to compare with other string to see if they are match.The other string can be any string. so, if someone can help me write the code,i would very much appreciate. Thanks in Advanced.

```
lsusb -v | awk '/iSerial/ {if ($2 == "3" || $2 == "2") {print $3}}'
```

anubhava, would this be right if i want to compare two strings.

```
 #!/bin/sh 
string="asd11ds"
output=$(lsusb -v | awk '/iSerial/ && ($2 == "3" || $2 == "2")) {print $3}')
 echo $output
 if [[$output==$string]];then
 echo"the two string are the same/are different"
 fi
```

Answer (score 1):

You use `$(...)` notation (command substitution) to store a command's output.

You awk can also be shortened:

```
output=$(lsusb -v | awk '/iSerial/ && ($2 == "3" || $2 == "2")) {print $3}')
```

Comment: anubhava, would this be right if i want to compare two strings.
                                                                           #!/bin/sh
    string="asd11ds"
    output=$(lsusb -v | awk '/iSerial/ && ($2 == "3" || $2 == "2"))      {print $3}')
echo $output

if [[$output==$string]];then
echo"the two string are the same/are different"
fi

Comment: Do not post code in comments. Edit your question and post your code there.

Comment: You need to use: `if [[ "$output" == "$string" ]]; then
 echo "the two string are the same/are different"
 fi`

Answer (score 0):

since your question tag is `bash`, I provide bash script

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

string="asd11ds"
output=$(lsusb -v | awk '/iSerial/ && ($2 == "3" || $2 == "2")) {print $3}')

echo $output

if [[ "$output" == "$string" ]]; then
 echo "the two strings are same"
else
 echo "the two strings are different"
fi
```

Comment: If this answer is helpful, you need vote it up, if it resolved your problem, you need accept it